# Narrowing down a type to an object with some property

Tags: typescript

I am trying to figure out why typescript doesn't like the following construction. The compiler errors are in the comments in the code.

```
const BAR = Symbol();

function foo<T>(that: T) {
  if (that !== null && typeof that === "object" && BAR in that) {
    // Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'unique symbol' can't be used to index type 'unknown'.
    // Property '[BAR]' does not exist on type 'unknown'.ts(7053)
    const bar = that[BAR];
    console.log(bar);
  }
}

function foo2<T>(that: T) {
  if (that !== null && typeof that === "object" && "BAR" in that) {
    // Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"BAR"' can't be used to index type 'unknown'.
    // Property 'BAR' does not exist on type 'unknown'.ts(7053)
    const bar = that["BAR"];
    console.log(bar);
  }
```

Shouldn't the `if` narrow down the type enough?

Comment: You should add the error you are getting to the question

Comment: The error is in the comments

Comment: @user3612643, I don't think the TS compiler plays well with supporting indexing by symbols at this time of writing. https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1863

Comment: @miqh The compiler also complains in foo2 that uses a string.

Comment: Check out type predicates: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? There's no way it's the best solution but it does work... [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.0.2#code/MYewdgzgLgBAQgQQEowLwwMoE8C2AjEAGwAoBKAbgCgAzAVzGCgEtwZqQQAeAFQD5ioACwCGUAFwxupGAG9KMGE2owBI2AEJU6MLUKEYAMgMwoWAA4BTEMqGi0WmACIQeAFYXGjw8ZEQACgBOIJYBpqqiADTwyKTScgoKoJCweMIBaCZqANqISAC6VAkwSRBEFgB0hCAA5sSpARTyMAC+lK009IwsYGwcAEw8-LbiknFNSirDMJrauvpGJuZWNmr26M5uHlBeC76BwRahWOFQUY65jrGyTYng0DD1GcNZ58iOBTfFd2WVNXVpjQUrXadAYzFYeyCIVMnD8MAsAA8oBYwAATCAwADWFiw1hgwjAWH4LlcEgJWCiZihEj8pAkJMUGJkMCyAH1FD0-HkJPRMWAQAB3HrNa5FAIWKC0AI9KnBDkwElUVpAA)

```
const BAR = Symbol();
function foo<T>(that: T) {
  if (that !== null && typeof that === "object" && hasProperty(that, BAR)) {
    const bar = that[BAR];
    console.log(bar);
  }
}

function foo2<T>(that: T) {
  if (that !== null && typeof that === "object" && hasProperty(that, "BAR")) {
    const bar = that["BAR"];
    console.log(bar);
  }
}

function hasProperty<P extends keyof any>(obj: any, prop: P): obj is { [_ in P]: unknown } {
    return prop in obj;
}
```

Comment: Looks good, but actually I think the ts compiler should automatically detect it...

Answer (score -1):

Since your generic function has no constraints, TS does not know what T will be. Therefore it complains. TS does static type analysis and not runtime analysis. Your if statement does not fall into the former category.

The power of TypeScript comes from its explicity, therefore if you already know that the attribute you will pass to the function (`that`) has as certain key (`BAR`), you should make that declaration.

If you want to stick with generics, that could be for example done like this:

```js
const BAR = 'BAR';

interface Barable {
  [BAR]: any,
}

function foo<T extends Barable>(that: T) {
  if (that !== null && typeof that === "object" && BAR in that) {
    const bar = that[BAR];
    console.log(bar);
  }
}

/*
string alternative:
 
interface Barable {
    BAR: any,
}

.. and then your string function from above

*/
```

Be aware that TS does not allow for interfaces to use symbols as keys.

---

**Some additional thoughts**

I don't know the reason that you use a generic here, but if you know you will pass this function an object, and you have some knowledge about the structure of that function, you could also just use an interface

Comment: Your answer is going into the wrong direction. Consider "that : T | Barable" instead of "T extends Barable". If "T extends Barable", obviously T the if is always true.

Comment: You did not really give any context so I assumed your if statement was an attempt to fix the error. As I said "if you already know that the attribute you will pass to the function (that) has as certain key (BAR), you should make that declaration." - well if not than obviously not. 
Instead of downvoting my answer and complaining you could describe your problem better and somebody might be able to give you a better answer.